# How to disable uib-timepicker converting time to Browser Timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angular

In my Database time is storing in UTC and in frontend I'm using uib-timepicker to edit/update time. I don't want uib-timepicker to convert time from server timezone to local timezone. I want uib-timepicker to display time in UTC only.

So, How to stop uib-timepicker converting timezone?

P.S: I don't have any problem in IE. Only in Chrome, it is converting timezone.

Comment: This is a **terrible** idea. Why on Earth (other than for your own convenience) would you show users UTC rather than local time in a date picker? You expect *every single one* of your users to not only *remember* to do the conversion when entering data but do so *accurately*? This is a recipe for getting bad data.

Comment: How is this browser-dependent in the first place? Can you show the raw response value you get from the server? Also show any code you use for passing that value to the time picker?

Comment: @Jared Smith, when a user enters input as 5:30 AM then I want it to be saved as 5:30 AM in database and I want it to be displayed as 5:30 AM in UI. I don't want any conversations here. Bcoz all my users are in same Timezone.

Comment: All my users are in the same timezone too, I just don't expect them to know how many hours we're ahead/behind UTC at all times and remember to *manually* make the adjustment. I like my data to be accurate.

Comment: If you want to store an abstract time like "5:30 AM" that only has business value to humans, store it as an abstract time in your DB. Don't go into absolute date/time territory. Just store it as the string "05:30" (hh:mm). Bonus: it's highly debuggable because it's human-readable out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Ates Goral, I am storing in string and as datetime variable in SQL. But I don't want uib timepicker to convert into local timezone. I want it to be displayed in UTC only.  User saves a time("05:30") and same value ("05:30") of time should be displayed everywhere. Because I have other read only fields where the data is displaying as per server value.

Comment: @Ranger Perhaps you didn't see my comment above. To repeat: "How is this browser-dependent in the first place? Can you show the raw response value you get from the server? Also show any code you use for passing that value to the time picker?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the timezone offset to convert it back to UTC :

```
return new Date(date.getTime() + (60000 * date.getTimezoneOffset()));
```

Comment: Replace 'date' with your date object.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following directive solves the issue for uib-timepicker using the uibDateParser from the uib-datepicker.

```
/**
 * UTC for timepicker
 */
angular.module('app').directive('uibTimepicker', function(uibDateParser) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) { // view
        if(!value) { return value; }

        return uibDateParser.fromTimezone(value, 'UTC');
      });

      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) { // model
        if(!value) { return value; }

        return uibDateParser.toTimezone(value, 'UTC');
      });

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Betty St, that helped with my issue.